# visual studio add in - add file to project

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

Google's not being my friend today.  Can anyone point me in the direction of any resources regarding creating add ins for Vs 2008?

Specifically, I have 2 tasks I cannot find any resources for:

1) Is a project currently open
2) How to add a file to the open project

If anyone has any resources / links it would be great.

Thank you

Frank

Comment: I got the same problem, i cant find out how to add a file to the active project. Also i would like to know if it is possible to add the file nested below another file ?

Comment: if the project is open, then: applicationObject.ItemOperations.AddExistingItem(destinationFile);

however - if no active project is open an exception is thrown.

Similarly applicationObject.OpenFile(EnvDTE.Constants.vsViewKindAny, destinationFile); doesnt throw an error - but doesnt open the file.

I've not had any time to progress this - so anything you find would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of documentation - including tutorials, samples and references - in MSDN, under "Visual Studio SDK":

- [Visual Studio 2005 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Visual Studio 2008 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx)